# Finding and printing items in list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I wish to draw things from lists and print them, like a database. How do I go about printing something called for by the user?

```
name = [John, Sam]
ages = [23, 7]
answer = input("Search by (n)ame or (a)ge")
if answer == "n":
    askName= input("what name?")
    # ?????
elif answer == "a":
    askAge = input("what age")
else start()
```

Comment: What would the output be? If I ask for the name "John" do you just give "John" back?

Comment: "Your student john is 23 years old"

Comment: What type of object are `John` and `Sam`. As posted these are not strings, so are they some sort of `Person` object? If they are an object, they would probably have an attribute to store the age, so you could just have a list of `Person` objects, rather than having 2 parallel lists.

Comment: What if there are multiple matches, e.g. search by age and there are 3 people with the same age?

Answer (score 3):

```
name = ['John', 'Sam']
ages = [23, 7]
answer = input("Search by (n)ame or (a)ge")
if answer == "n":
    askName= input("what name?")
    if askName in name:
        print(ages[name.index(askName)])
elif answer == "a":
    askAge = input("what age")
    if askAge in ages:
        print(name[ages.index(askAge)])
```

With `if askName in name` you can check if `askName` is in the `name` list. If it is, you can get the index with `index()` and access the value in the `ages` list with it. Getting the name for an age works the same way.

Comment: It should be pointed out this will return the index of the first occurrence of the value specified. In cases where there are students that have the same name/age this could potentially produce the wrong output.

Comment: @IanAuld You're right. But if there are students with the same name/age, there is no way to find out who is who. In that case you would need some kind of id.

Comment: Yes there is. It can be done with a manual for loop to return all the matches .

Comment: @IanAuld You would still not know what the correct value is. Let's say we have `['Katy', 'Katy']` and `[23, 51]`. How old is Katy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
userlist = [
    {'name':'John', 'age':23},
    {'name':'Sam', 'age':7},
    {'name':'Anna', 'age':7},
    {'name':'John', 'age':10},
]

answer = input("Search by (n)ame or (a)ge")
if answer == "n":
    askName= input("what name?")
    for i in userlist:
        if i['name'] == askName:
            print('name: '+askName+', age: '+str(i['age']))
elif answer == "a":
    askAge = input("what age")
    for i in userlist:
        if i['age'] == int(askAge):
            print('name: '+str(i['name'])+', age: '+askAge)
```

Students can have same names and ages so output will be like this:

```
Search by (n)ame or (a)gen
what name?Sam
name: Sam, age: 7

Search by (n)ame or (a)gea
what age7
name: Sam, age: 7
name: Anna, age: 7
```

To avoid this you can select students by ID:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
userlist = [
    {'name':'John', 'age':23},
    {'name':'Sam', 'age':7},
    {'name':'Anna', 'age':7},
    {'name':'John', 'age':10},
]

answer = input("Search by (n)ame or (a)ge or (i)d\n")
if answer == "n":
    askName= input("what name?\n")
    for i in userlist:
        if i['name'] == askName:
            print('name: '+askName+', age: '+str(i['age']))
elif answer == "a":
    askAge = input("what age?\n")
    for i in userlist:
        if i['age'] == int(askAge):
            print('name: '+str(i['name'])+', age: '+askAge)
elif answer == "i":
    askId = input("what id?\n")
    print('id: ' + askId + ',name: '+str(userlist[int(askId)]['name'])+', age: '+str(userlist[int(askId)]['age']))
```

Output:

```
Search by (n)ame or (a)ge or (i)d
i
what id?
1
id: 1,name: Sam, age: 7
```